# what is the best way to implement group chat in XMPP ejabberd server pubsub or MUC to make group chats like whatsapp

Tags: android, xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd, groupchat

i am implementing group chat on XMPP ejabberd server so what is the best option? Pubsub or MUC?
MUC has only persistent groups which means as soon as the user goes offline the user leaves the group. Or instead i can implement using pubsub which does not have the functionality like presence and other things, so i would have to build them myself. so whats my best option?

Comment: also which would be a better way? either to edit XMPP ejabberd server or handle everything using items and payloads in pubsub?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Whatsapp like chatroom on top of MUC room. You would benefit from Message Archive support for MUC that will allow you to bypass the presence limitation by querying the history.

Comment: One question, AFAIK the user will not receive message if he's offline from MUC Room, how can we handle such situation except history?